# Trying to override POST method with PUT but method override not working

Tags: html, node.js, overriding

I am using nodejs and I have installed method override as part of my package.

I have a form that I am using to update a book in my mongoDB. The bookSchema is as follows:

```
const bookSchema=new mongoose.Schema({
title: {type: String, required: true},
description: {type: String},
publishDate: {type: Date, required: true },
pageCount: {type: Number, required: true},
createdAt: {type: Date, required: true, default: Date.now},
coverImage: {type: Buffer, required: true},
coverImageType: {type: String, required: true},
author: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: 'Author'}})
```

I have the following HTML form with form:

```
<h2>Edit Book</h2>
<form action="/books/<%= book.id %>?=_method=PUT" method="POST" >  
    <%- include('_form_fields')%>  
    <a href="/books/<%= book.id %>">Cancel</a>
    <button type="submit">Update</button>
</form>
```

The form fields are saved in a seperate ejs file called _form_fields.ejs.
The problem is that when I click the "Update" button on the form above, I get the following error in the browser:

"`Cannot POST /books/6027aadff143f81a30841721`"

but I'm expecting the error to be

"`Cannot PUT /books/6027aadff143f81a30841721`"

since I've used method override. As a result, the button is not picking up "put action" which is defined in my routes.

I have already successful implemented method override on another form in this project but this was is not working.

for addition information, I have included my router.put code below:

```
router.put('/:id',async (req, res)=>{

let book
console.log("Clicked")

try{
    book=await Book.findById(req.params.id)
    book.title=req.body.title
    book.author=req.body.author
    book.publishDate=new Date(req.body.publishDate)
    book.pageCount=req.body.pageCount
    book.description=req.body.description
    if (req.body.coverImage!=null && req.body.coverImage!==""){
        saveCover(book, req.body.coverImage)
    }
    await book.save()
    
    res.redirect(`/books/${book.id}`)
}catch(err){
    
    if(book!=null){
        
        renderEditPage(res, book, true)
    } else{
        res.redirect('/')}}})
```

Comment: the browser does not know, that the server will handle a POST with _method=PUT the same way as a PUT

Comment: @thejonny, I implemented this method on another form and the browser seemed to know that I'm overriding POST with put . I'm confused why it's no longer working because I followed the same procedure.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured out that my syntax was wrong:

`?=_method=PUT"` should have been `?_method=PUT"`

```
    <h2>Edit Book</h2>
<form action="/books/<%= book.id %>?_method=PUT" method="POST" >  
    <%- include('_form_fields')%>  
    <a href="/books/<%= book.id %>">Cancel</a>
    <button type="submit">Update</button>
</form>
```

Lesson learned: always check your code for typos